# Storing shapefile in PostgreSQL database as a table using PHP?

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, php, command-line

I want to create a table from a shapefile in PostgreSQL. To do that, I can run this command in cmd:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 -W LATIN1 E:\Any\THA_adm public.test123 | psql -h localhost -d DATA -U postgres -w 123;
```

This works, but I want to run it from PHP. How can I do that, I tried PHP functions:

1. shell_exec()
2. exec()
3. system()

but did not work. Is there any other way to create a table from shape in PHP or run this command?

Comment: Why did exec() not work? What was the error? Did you do something similar than in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259089/execute-gdal-translate-in-php-using-exec?

Comment: Finally its works, Don't know what was the problem

Comment: Nice. I copy my comment as an answer then.

Comment: exec() works if used like in this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259089/execute-gdal-translate-in-php-using-exec

Comment: actually exec() worked, I don't know what was the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was "by using exec() as in an example showed in the answer to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259089/execute-gdal-translate-in-php-using-exec".

Comment: This link doesn't work, what's the answer please ?

Comment: Don't remember. Check the links on that deleted page.

Comment: How can I do that ? GSE say : "This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation."

Comment: I see there "Here are some similar questions that might be relevant" and a bunch of links.

Comment: Perfect, I used this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914402/php-exec-is-not-executing-the-command

Answer (score 2):

I experienced exactly the same problem (command works in cmd but nothing when called via PHP). What helped me a lot was to retrieve the error message (by adding: 2>&1'& $output). MY command looked something like:

```
?php
exec("\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\shp2pgsql.exe\" -s 28992 -I -W 
latin1 D:\somefolder\someshape.shp someschema.example_shape | psql -U postgres -h localhost -d somedbname 2>&1", $output);
foreach ($output as $key => $value)
{echo $value;}
?>
```

It returned "'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." My fix was to define the full path of the psql executable in the command like this:

```
<?php
exec("\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\shp2pgsql.exe\" -s 28992 -I -W 
latin1 D:\somefolder\someshape.shp someschema.example_shape | \"C:\Program 
Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\psql.exe\" -U postgres -h localhost -d somedbname");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/333545), a native PHP alternative to using *evil* `eval()` and *shp2pgsql* utility would be my [PHP Shapefile](https://github.com/gasparesganga/php-shapefile) library, that can read and write any ESRI Shapefile natively in PHP.

It is a free, open source, native PHP library, does not require any third party dependency and is actively maintained.