# Load a shapefile in PostgreSQL database with PHP

Tags: postgis, shapefile, php, shp2pgsql

I am trying to load a shapefile in a PostGIS database using the exec() command. I have read the format I have to follow from [here](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg) and I checked several similar questions from the [forum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99557/how-can-i-store-shape-file-in-postgress-database-as-a-table-using-php).

Based on the above I wrote this script:

> `$command = 'shp2pgsql -s 2100 -d /home/enomix/www/EsoterikoFinal/Maps/shps/nodes.shp  | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d shapeDb -U postgres -W xxx';
>   $output = exec($command);
>   print_r($output);`

What I want is to load the shapefile into a newly created table which is in a database called 'shapeDb'. Every time I load a shapefile I want the previous table to be dropped and a new table to be created (that's why I use the -d option). I have defined a full path for my shapefile (should I define a relative one like: "shps/nodes"?)

When I run the script I get nothing back as a response although I have a:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Its the first time I do something like this. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**EDITED**

Running the above command on the terminal it works fine. But I still can not figure out how to drop the previous table and create a new one each time I run the query. And also why the exec command doesn't work!

**EDITED II**

Now I made it work. The -W xxx was causing problems. I don't know why though (its just the password). I run my script like this:

```
$command = 'shp2pgsql -s 2100 /home/enomix/www/EsoterikoFinal/Maps/shps/nodes.shp  | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d esoteriko -U postgres';
exec($command,$out,$ret);
```

**BUT still I can not figure out how to drop the table each time and create a new one. ANY IDEAS?**

**EDITED III**

This works now:

```
$command = 'shp2pgsql -s 2100 -d /home/enomix/www/EsoterikoFinal/Maps/shps/nodes.shp  | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d esoteriko -U postgres';
exec($command,$out,$ret);
```

Note: Don't forget to add the postgis extension to your postgresql database like:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works now:

```
$command = 'shp2pgsql -s 2100 -d /home/enomix/www/EsoterikoFinal/Maps/shps/nodes.shp  | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d esoteriko -U postgres';
```

exec($command,$out,$ret);

Answer (score 3):

First of all, 
You need to add a new environment variable called `PGPASSWORD`

```
    $ export PGPASSWORD='password'
```

But, if you try to set as usual, the www-data doesn't see the variable, so you need to add the line `PGPASSWORD='password'` to the `/etc/apache2/envvar`.

Test if this works typing:

```
    sudo -u www-data bash -c "<the_command_shp2pgsql>"
```

Then you can run the php script bellow as `www-data` the custom apache user.

```
    $command  "shp2pgsql -a -k -s <SRID> /<directory_of_shapes>/<your_shape_file>.shp <postgis_table>  | psql -h <your_host_name> -p 5432 -d <your-database> -U postgres ";

    $retorno = shell_exec($command);
    acho $retorno;
```

the `<directory_of_shapes>` must have `www-data` permission access.

Comment: +1 for hint to adding the Environment Variable, but export doesn't worked for me, instead I used putenv("PGPASSWORD=$pw"); and unset it with putenv('PGPASSWORD');

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using *evil* `eval()` would be my [PHP Shapefile](https://github.com/gasparesganga/php-shapefile) library, that can read and write any ESRI Shapefile natively in PHP.

I (and many others, actually) have been using it for this very same scope, loading tons of Shapefiles into PostgreSQL, thanks to the WKT output provided by the library and PostGIS [`ST_GeomFromText()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) function.

It is a free, open source, native PHP library, does not require any third party dependency and is actively maintained.

Comment: Are there any recommended libraries for writing to PostGIS with your library?  It looks quite simple to get table parameters and data needed to create a table structure with your library so I'm getting ready to dig in, but if you have any recommendations for pushing out to PostGIS I'd like to start with that too. Thanks!

Comment: Probably PDO and nothing else. Some simple PHP code, relying on my library to read the Shapefile and PDO to execute some queries. Then, if you feel fancy and want to make it dynamic, you could add some PL/pgSQL functions server-side to create tables and structures... that's the way I have always done. ST_GeomFromText() will accept WKT output provided by the library. It was originally designed for this very scope. it look simple and it is ;)